# Increase font size throughout project on click

Tags: jquery, css

I'm designing a web application for a client that's primarily targeted at the elderly. They want a feature in which, on click of a button, the font-size throughout the project increases/decreases.

What would be an optimal method of doing so? The only solution I could come up with was, provide each page with the toggle button and then using jquery do something like

```
...
$('body').css('font-size', '20px');
...
```

I'm not sure if this is an elegant method given that various `p, h1, h2...` have different font-sizes assigned to them and that this would involve clicks on each page rather than one click in general.

Comment: You would have to size all text in `rem`s (or `em`s.) Oh, and jquery would only affect one page at a time unless you swap out stylesheets.

Comment: like he ^ said, you can set a default size for the elements in px then change them using em. Then when you change the body px the elements will scale in size with it. Saving the value in a cookie will allow you to save and get the preferred font size of the user

Comment: The first guys method is the best but for alternatives sake (I would recommend the first)

you could do something like this.

http://jsfiddle.net/wuTxc/

Like I said I would recommend the rem / ems method over this though

Comment: Is this a real (single-page) application, or a site (collection of pages)? In the latter case, you would need e.g. cookies to store the size setting so that it workds across pages. Alternatively, do not set `body` font size at all, set all other font sizes in percentages (if at all), and include a link to a page that teaches people to use font size setting commanda in popular browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy enough, use relative font sizes on all elements that descend from `body` - which is all the contextual elements.

```
body{
    font-size: 20px; /*This is our default*/
}

h1{
   font-size: 1em; /*Relative to the body, this will also be 20px*/
}

h2{
   font-size:0.8em; /*This will be 20 * 0.8 = 16px;*/
}

h3{
   font-size:80%; /*This is the same thing as above - 20 * 80% = 16px; */
}

h1.huge{
    font-size:1.2em; /*This one will be 20 * 1.2 = 24px */
}
```

So now we have set the stage. All elements have a relative font size based on the `body`. Now all you need to do to adjust every element's font size is to adjust the font size of the `body` element on a click:

```
var button = document.getElementById('.myButton');
button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var body = document.querySelector('body');
    body.style.fontSize = '25px';
});
```

(You could also get fancy and track the click of this button in `localStorage` or just a cookie to remember this selection across pages)

And now our sizes will resolve like this:

```
h1{
   font-size: 1em; /*25px*/
}

h2{
   font-size:0.8em; /*This will be 25 * 0.8 = 20px;*/
}

h3{
   font-size:80%; /*This is the same thing as above - 24 * 80% = 20px; */
}

h1.huge{
    font-size:1.2em; /*This one will be 25 * 1.2 = 30px */
}
```

**Note**: Relative font sizes are actually calculated based on the parent element, not necessarily the `body`. That means if you have a relative font size defined for an element that has a parent with a relative font size, you'll need to do a bit of math:

```
body{
    font-size:25px;
}

div.container{
    font-size: 0.8em; /* 20px if a child of body */
}

div.container > p{
    font-size:0.8em; /* 25px * 0.8 * 0.8 = 16px; */
}
```